# Problems with, or best practices for, passing data back through eventargs?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, eventargs

I've got a non-GUI class that generates events as to what it is doing (which are in turn used by a Form to display to the user the progress).

One of the events is a `AboutToDoSomethingDestructiveEvent`.  Now we want to have the Form display a dialog to the user when `AboutToDoSomethingDestructiveEvent` is raised, asking them if they would like `SomethingDestructive` to happen.  If they select no, then we would set a value on the customer `EventArgs` and the original form would read that value and then skip doing `SomethingDestructive`.

Is this a proper use of Events and `EventArgs`?  Are there problems with this approach?  Are there any best practices for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is so good there's even a class in the .NET Framework for this: [CancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx)

Comment: Yup. Creating your own `EventArgs` which extends `CancelEventArgs` would be a very good solution here I think :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are thinking is the proper way to do it. The Console.CancelKeyPress event is essentially the same thing.

[Console.CancelKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a proper approach, as long as you have your own EventArgs, which are inheriting from System.EventArgs. It is very common, the best example I can think of is in PostSharp with the FlowBehavior.